# Direct the compiler how to optimize my code

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction

How I can say to the compiler how to optimize something or what some call to function.
I mean like create allocate method and let the compiler optimize it as it optimize it with `malloc` or `new`.

Or like if somewhere in the code the function X is called and it's return value is not used then delete this call. (Function from .lib that the compiler don't know a piece about it)

There are options for this?

For example:

```
auto val=X(); //Use the return value
X(); //Don't use
auto t=allocate<T>(); //Allocate on heap
t->Show(val); //Run single function and don't use it's pointer somewhere (Save it after the function is exit)
```

And optimize it to:

```
X(); //First line, just call it
T().Show(val); //Combines third and fourth lines, Allocate on stack and run the single function
```

If you asking 'why you need this?' I am creating programming language with my own GC and heap. (And lot of things too)

It translates to C++ then I don't want to optimize the code while translate it. (It's gonna be a pain)
Because I can call functions randomly in places. (I can't detect if their values are used or not)

Comment: Is the language you're designing 1) a statically compiled language 2) a just-in-time language, or 3) an interpreted language?

Comment: "Function from .lib that the compiler don't know a piece about it" if the compiler doesn't know a function doesn't have any side effects, it can't optimize it away (or rather, it would be an error to do so). I'd like to mention that C++ isn't a terribly great compile target.

Comment: @NickODell Interpreted. (Somhow C# to C++)

Comment: @Cubic Then that's what I want... Put define before the function or something to tell the compiler then function's return value isn't used then remove the call.

Comment: @YanaiBugu if you can generate code to tell a compiler to throw the next line away, you can just throw the next line away yourself.

Comment: @Cubic I know but it'll be a pain to optimize my own code while translate it. (It's scanner -> parser -> codegen, but it'll be still pain...)

Comment: @YanaiBugu, C++ is a statically compiled language, so I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't think any c++ compiler does optimizations to allocate heap objects on the stack. Besides why would you want to translate an interpreted (jitted?, interpreted would directly execute the statements instead of translating/compiling them first) language to c++ (which is afterall a statically compiled lanuage, so getting that to work as a jit (not to mention performantely) is probably going to be a major pita)? Something like java or .net bytecode seems much more sensible for that in my opinion.

Comment: @NickODell To tell the compiler to remove call to function when it's return value isn't used. (Even if the function is in lib and it doesn't know about the code inside the function)

Comment: @Grizzly It's not JIT it's something that interpret kind of C# to C++ and I don't know... just help the compiler I don't mind my example.

Comment: @YanaiBugu, think about it like this: suppose you have a `printf` statement. How does it know it's not okay to optimize it out?

Comment: @NickODell It doesn't optimize it out, by the way memcpy and copying loop it optimize it away to copy paste like `a=b;`.

Comment: @YanaiBugu: So how would you execute your code? Since you say it is an interpreted language you don't statically compile the code beforehand and you can't execute c++ code without compiling it, which would make it a jit (at least I don't see any other way, since you need to compile it somewhere. For optimizing things out: Nothing in standard c++, you might find compiler specific extensions, which would give the compiler the knowledge though (for gcc the `pure` attribute might help). How it uses it is out off your hands of course.

Comment: @Grizzly Oops I mean parsed\translated language. I know it's not easy, because of it I target it... To make C++ easy to use. It's not really it but it is more to create performanceful (?) and very easy.

Comment: So it's actually meant to be a compiled language. That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Grizzly Compiled? Sorry for my pool english but compiled it's not like C# or C++? Translated or converted language it's my proglang type, no?

Comment: You translate to c++ which is subsequently compiled, don't you (or do you expect the translation result to be manually modified by the programmer?). As such I would definately call it a compiled language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Optimization is compiler-specific, so you'll need to look in your compiler's documentation to see what optimization "hints" it allows you to put in code.  For example, here are some of GCC's [function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

- The `malloc` attribute tells the compiler that if the function returns a non-null pointer, it's always a "new" area of memory, not another pointer to something that's already been allocated.  You'd probably want to use this on a function that wraps the real `malloc()`.
- The `const` attribute (different from the ordinary `const` keyword) says that the function's return value depends solely on its arguments and has no side effects, so it's safe for the compiler to eliminate duplicate calls with the same arguments.
- The `noreturn` attribute tells the compiler that a function never returns; you'd use this on functions that terminate the program, like C's `exit()`.

Attributes go on the declaration of a function, typically in a header file, so you can use them even if the function's implementation is in a compiled library that'll be linked in later.  But remember that function attributes are promises from you to the compiler:  if you declare a function with the `noreturn` attribute, for example, and then implement it with code that actually can return, strange things may happen at runtime when it does.

---

You can also use function attributes to help with correctness checking:

- The `nonnull` attribute tells the compiler that certain (pointer) arguments aren't supposed to be null, so it can issue warnings if it detects that they might be.
- The `format` argument tells the compiler that the function takes a format string like C's `printf()`, so it can check that the types of the variadic arguments match the corresponding format codes in the format string.  (For example, you shouldn't write "`%s`" in the format string but then pass an integer as its value.)

Comment: I am using VC++, there are things like those in VC++? (Windows =\)

Comment: Probably, but I don't know since I don't use VC++.  Check the documentation.